# Console is giving no error, however my code is doing nothing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm using Discord.py and replit to write a bot. I'm starting off super simple, I simply want my bot to respond to my hello.
[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIlkq.png)
[Here is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqWKX.png)

I have troubleshooted in the neighborhood of 7 or 8 errors with this code (I know it's sad that 20 lines of code gave me this much trouble) and gotten all of that fixed. So now that the console isn't showing any errors, I'm confused why nothing is happening when I type in $hello to my bot on discord.

Other info: My discord bot does go online when I hit run, which tells me the token stuff is working. I ran into problems on line 4 which was a whole "Intents" fiasco, this is my first time using the Intents keyword and so I would assume the issue lies somewhere in there.
Other idea: This may have something to do with the console saying "Shard ID None"?

Comment: Try putting a `print` statement in your on_message function to see if your discord bot is receiving these notifications.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't post images of code or text. Please copy and paste the text into your post and put it in a code block. Also check out this article on [Minimal Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your bot is missing the message_content intent.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you feedback!!! I will fix all of this I appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Give the bot the `message_content` intent in the constructor and enable it in the Developer Dashboard

**Detailed Answer**

Make a variable called `intents = discord.Intents.default()`.
After that set `intents.message_content = True` and pass it to your `discord.Client` constrcutor (`intents=intents` instead of `intents=discord.Intents.default()`).

Now go to the Discord Developer Dashboard, open your application, head to "Bot" and enable the "Message Content Intent" in the "Privileged Gateway Intents" section.

**Make sure this is enabled!**
[image]

Comment: Hey everyone we got it working!! Thank you all so much!

Let me show you the code that it is running and is now fully operational. I removed the old line 4 completely, and replaced it with this stuff:

4    intents = discord.Intents.default()
5    intents.message_content = True
6    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

One other note, as posted by Kejax, I had "message content intent" off, that also stopped it from working! So after fixing both of those things we are in the clear :)